# Laravel 5.5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I'm trying to post some data trough an ajax request.

This is the javascript code inside my view.blade.php which refers to http://mysite/element/edit/{id}

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#append-content" ).sortable({ handle: '.composer-row-header-handle' }).bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {

            var rowID = $('.composer-row').map(function(){
                return $(this).attr("id");
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sort/store",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    rowID: rowID
                },
                success: function(order){
                    console.log(rowID)
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(rowID)
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and inside the same file I have inserted the relative _token meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then I set up a POST route inside my route file

```
Route::post('element/edit/sort/store', 'ElementsController@sort');
```

And my ElementsController sort function is

```
public function sort(Request $request)
{
    $rowID = $request->input('rowID');
    $i = 1;

    foreach($rowID as $val) {
        $val = str_replace("row-", "", $val);
        DB::table('element')
            ->where('refID', 1)
            ->where('rowID', $val)
            ->update(
                [
                    'rowORDER' => $i,
                ]
            );
        $i++;
    }
}
```

But then when i try to reorder the log the response is

```
jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4 POST http://mysite/element/edit/sort/store 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And if I try to open the link in a new page this is the result

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNkdb.png)

Thanks in advance for every answer

Comment: When you try to open the link in a new page you are using `GET` method instead `POST`, so you got `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. As for ajax call just check your laravel log file.

Comment: But I specified ajax to use type `POST`

Comment: Have you checked your ajex is hitting at which route? is it hitting the route you have mentioned in the comment, or hitting something else?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

probably worked for too many hours. I was editing sort function on wrong Controller file.

Answer (score 0):

change {{URL::to('element/edit/sort/store')}} and  try